# Can I move a hard drive from a MacBook 13 to a MacBook 15?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, startup

I'm thinking of upgrading my machine to a 15" and wondering if I can just move the hard drive over and put a new one in the 13"?

The reason is my 13" Macbook has a 2TB HDD and I'd rather keep that for myself in a new MacBook 15 and put a smaller one in the 13".

From a mid-2012 13" MacBook Pro.

Comment: If any of the two is a retina macbook this is definitely a no go.

Comment: Which model and year of each hardware?

Comment: From a 2012 Release 13" MacBook Pro. I was hoping for a 2012 or newer 15" Macbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no space for a SATA drive in the latest 15" MBPs (retina), so, unless you get an older model (pre 2012), there's no way of using your old drive in the new macbook.

See, for example: https://www.ifixit.com/Device/MacBook_Pro_15%22_Retina_Display_Mid_2014

Comment: I was looking at 2012, so that'd be a no-go. Out of academic interest, is it possible when the drive types are the same?

Comment: And on another note ... does that mean the max hard-drive size in a 15" MBP is 1TB at the moment? (presumably limited to PCIe SSD drives...)

Comment: It should be possible, when my 2008 13" Unibody Macbook died and I got a 2011 13" MBP, I simply swapped the drives.

Yes, I guess the SSD size is limited by the existing technology and/or your budget. Keep in mind, if you want to replace the SSD, that Yosemite disables TRIM for third-party SSDs, check out the existing discussions about SSDs, TRIM and Yosemite.

Comment: You should be able to if you are getting the non-retina version. The retina versions are not upgradeable.